# Programmatically select Nth option select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a script that populates a select box.  Meaning that I don't know the values or the number items that will be in that box.

I want to make another script that emulates the behavior selecting the Nth item in that box.  I've read around and can't figure out how to do this.  I'm sure that there is an easy option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `eq()` method to select the Nth item in a matched set. From there you can set the `selected` property of the `option` to `true` to select it. Try this:

```
$('#mySelect option').eq(2).prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
```

Note that the index given to `eq()` is zero-based, so the above would select the third `option` element.

Also note that when you select an `option` programmatically, no events are raised. If you require the event, you would need to use `trigger()` to fire it manually.

Comment: Just tested and this does exactly what you said it would.  However, it does not trigger an "onchange" event from the select box.  Any way to make that happen?  Otherwise I can find another easy fix for that.

Comment: I updated my answer for you. When you select an `option` programmatically, no events are raised. If you require the event, you would need to use `trigger()` to fire it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [**`selectedIndex`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectedIndex) property:

```
$('select').prop('selectedIndex',  3);
```

You can chain a `change()` method to trigger any `change()` events:

**Snippet:**

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  console.log('changed');
});

$('select').prop('selectedIndex',  3).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Not me</option>
  <option>Not me</option>
  <option>Not me</option>
  <option>Select me!</option>
  <option>Not me</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work.  Lets say the select element had the div Id "myDiv" how would it look to select the second option with this method? I've tried: ('#myDiv option').prop('selectedIndex',  1).change();

Comment: Omit `option`.  You want to set the property on the `select` element:  `$('#myDiv').prop('selectedIndex', 1).change();`

Comment: Thank you so very much. I ended up choosing the other answer because it was a bit easier for me to get working.  But both seem to be totally right. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
   var selectedOption = $(this).prop('selected', true)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the select element as an object or in a loop.

```
$('select').each(function() {
   if( /*Some Filter*/ ){
      $(this).val($(this).find('option').eq(2).val()).trigger('change');
   }
});
```

It worked for me.

Tested on Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  console.log('changed');
});

$('select').prop('selectedIndex',  3).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Not me</option>
  <option>Not me</option>
  <option>Not me</option>
  <option>Select me!</option>
  <option>Not me</option>
</select>
```